# Sonarqube 5.0 upgrade error

Tags: mysql, innodb, sonarqube

When upgrading from sonarqube 4.5.2 to 5.0 on a system using mysql 5.5 we get the following error during migration process. Seems like the upgrade is using something that isn't supported by the InnoDB-Engine. I did not find any restrictions concerning InnoDB mentioned by sonarqube. So is there any way we can fix this by changing configuration of our sonarqube database?

Thanks in advance!

**Log:**

```
2015.01.19 17:43:21 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator]  Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.FeedSnapshotSourcesUpdatedAt
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1654) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1463) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.UpsertImpl.addBatch(UpsertImpl.java:42) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.MassUpdate$1.handle(MassUpdate.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.MassUpdate.execute(MassUpdate.java:76) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v50.FeedSnapshotSourcesUpdatedAt.execute(FeedSnapshotSourcesUpdatedAt.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.BaseDataChange.execute(BaseDataChange.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:94) ~[sonar-server-5.0.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:455) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:206) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:567) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2595) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2227) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:356) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:213) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:217) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgBlockPassNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgBlockPassNode.java:66) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:357) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:312) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:346) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:204) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.whenNoTest(WhenOneArgNode.java:27) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.WhenOneArgNode.when(WhenOneArgNode.java:45) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CaseNode.interpret(CaseNode.java:132) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:228) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:97) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_72]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1583) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar:na]
... 173 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to configure MySQL to use the correct BINLOG format. You should try to set it to `MIXED` or `ROW` (if `MIXED` does not work).

You can learn more about this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58459/mysql-error-impossible-to-write-to-binary-log